# SFML/C++ Sprite is being displayed as a white box due to going out of scope, don't know where

Tags: c++, scope, sfml

Title describes everything, I'm trying to do a tile-based engine, but i can't continue because I just can't find where the texture goes out of scope.

Thank you.

My code:

ImageManager.h

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>

class ImageManager{
    std::vector<sf::Texture> textureList;
public:

    void AddTexture(sf::Texture);
    sf::Texture getIndex(int index) const;
};
```

ImageManager.cpp

```
#include "imageManager.h"

void ImageManager::AddTexture(sf::Texture texture){
    textureList.push_back(texture);
}

sf::Texture ImageManager::getIndex(int index) const{
    return textureList[index];
}
```

Tile.h

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <memory>

class Tile{
    sf::Sprite sprite;

public:
    Tile(sf::Texture texture);

    void draw(int x, int y, sf::RenderWindow* rw);
};
```

Tile.cpp

```
#include "Tile.h"

Tile::Tile(sf::Texture texture){
    sprite.setTexture(texture);
}

void Tile::draw(int x, int y, sf::RenderWindow* rw){
    sprite.setPosition(x, y);
    rw->draw(sprite);
}
```

Comment: This seems like the sort of problem that would *really* benefit from an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @NathanTuggy Ok, done. I thought that adding the full code would help because it's actual compilable code, but if these 4 files are enough, great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor takes as argument a copy of the original texture which dies at the end of the scope. Use a (const) reference instead.

Also, your ImageManager will copy textures when its vector is resized and therefore all sprites will lose their textures. Either use a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<sf::Texture>>` or use [Thor](http://www.bromeon.ch/libraries/thor/)'s resource manager (or any other good library actually).

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Hiura's answer for future readers, It's important to remember that `sf::Sprite` is just a pointer to a `sf::Texture` along with some drawing information. If the `sf::Texture` a `sf::Sprite` is pointing to gets destroyed, the `sf::Sprite` no-longer has texture information to work with. As Hiura said, the constructor of `Tile` copies a `sf::Texture` passed to it, points the `sf::Sprite` at the copy, then destroys the copy, leaving the `sf::Sprite` with no `sf::Texture`. By instead passing a reference to a `sf::Texture`, the `sf::Sprite` will be pointed to the original `sf::Texture`